# Does the change of an environment varibale in docker-compose.yaml require a rebuild?

Tags: docker-compose

We have a docker-compose.yaml file in which a parameter APP_DEBUG from .env.local, which sets if xdebug is active or not:

```
php-fpm:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
        args:
            - TIMEZONE=Europe/Berlin
            - WITH_XDEBUG=${APP_DEBUG}
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-php-fpm
    environment:
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=docker.for.mac.localhost remote_connect_back=0 remote_enable=1 remote_autostart=1 remote_port=9009"
        PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=docker-server"
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www:cached
    ports:
        - ${HOST_WEB_PORT}:80
```

If I have my container up and running and want to switch xdebug or or off, is "stop" and "start" enough for the container to react to the change or do I need to do "down" and "up" or even a new build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build config options are applied at build time. So, think you are going to need to build your image and run the container again.

Source [Build docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build)